Text after a table does not appear to be aligned anymore
I have text before and after a table but the text after the table is not as left aligned as before. How can I fix this?

\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry, mhchem, textgreek, tabularx, longtable}
\geometry{a4paper, left=2cm, right=2cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=3cm }
\title{Staining of differentiated macrophages\vspace*{-1.5cm}}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\setcounter{table}{0}
\section{Reagents} 
\section{Methods}
    test text
    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \caption{Staining panel for Milteny MacsQuant 10 (8 colors)}
        \label{tab:stain_macs}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
            \hline
            &CD14&CD11b&CD206&CD86&CD80&CD163&L/D \\
            \hline
            Fluorophore&PacificBue&BV510&FITC&PE&PE/Cy7&AF647&NearIR \\
            \hline
            Laser&Violet&Violet&Blue&Blue&Blue&Red&Red \\
            \hline
            Filter&V1&V1&B1&B2&B4&R1&R2 \\
            \hline
            Highest in&Mono&Mono/M0&M2&M1&M1&M2&\\
            \hline
            Dilution&1:80&\textit{1:50}&1:50&\textit{1:50}&1:50&\textit{1:50}&\textit{1:50}\\
            \hline  
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
    
    test text

If I use a line break \\ after the table it corrects this issue, but only as long there is text in front of the table, if i remove the first "test text", i get the error "there is no line here to end. t"

The empty line after your table will start a new paragraph and new paragraphs are indented by default.

Following the principle that the most reliable treatment of a floating table and the text that precedes and follows it is to have a blank line above and another below it, the recommended method to avoid indentation of the following text is to precede it by \noindent,
